# Symfony4 doctrine utf8mb4 not detected

Tags: symfony, doctrine

i have an issue with doctrine and symfony4.1, he don't take my charset parameter.

I have always my tables with charset utf8 and collate utf8_unicode_ci.

I have tried with mariadb / mysql and nothing work he never detect my charset configuration.

I have drop my database, recreate and migrate mutiple times and clear cache everytime. But he doesn't work.

commands :

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
php bin/console make:migration
php bin/console doctrine:migration:migrate
```

here my configuration file :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%env(DATABASE_MASTER_HOST)%"
        dbname:   "%env(DATABASE_DBNAME)%"
        user:     "%env(DATABASE_USER)%"
        password: "%env(DATABASE_PASSWORD)%"
        slaves:
            slave1:
                host:     "%env(DATABASE_SLAVE_HOST)%"
                dbname:   "%env(DATABASE_DBNAME)%"
                user:     "%env(DATABASE_USER)%"
                password: "%env(DATABASE_PASSWORD)%"
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci                        
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
        dql:
            string_functions:
                GROUP_CONCAT: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\GroupConcat
                IF: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\IfElse
                FIND_IN_SET: App\DQL\FindInSet
```

When i add to my sql configuration file :

```
character-set-server = utf8mb4          
collation-server     = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

My database is created with utf8mb4_unicode_ci
but my tables is always generate with utf8 / utf8_unicode_ci

It work if i create my entity with the options parameter:

```
@ORM\Table(options={"charset":"utf8mb4"}...)
```

But i don't want to change all my table like that and my jointable are always with utf8.

why he don't take my configuration of charset.

It look likes something doens't work when i use MasterSlaveConnection.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: bug reported : https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/900